# Assign by reference

Tags: go, pass-by-reference

I am stuck with a small assignment by reference issue in Go. I tried to mimic the problem in the below code.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type tRes struct {
    a string
    b interface{}
}

func get(t string, r interface{}) error {
    var res tRes
    switch t {
    case "string":
        res = tRes{
            a: "XYZ",
            b: "Nobody",
        }
    case "int":
        res = tRes{
            a: "XYZ",
            b: 10,
        }
    }
    // r = &res.b
    j, _ := json.Marshal(res.b)
    json.Unmarshal(j, &r)
    return nil
}

func main() {
    var b string
    get("string", &b)
    fmt.Println(b)
    
    var i int
    get("int", &i)
    fmt.Println(i)
}
```

In the code, get method returns a value based on the type. If I use `r = &res.b` it does not work whereas `j, _ := json.Marshal(res.b) json.Unmarshal(j, &r)` works. I do not want to do json marshal and unmarshal on a very big object as in the actual code, I am calling an API that returns a big object. I do json unmarshal to create the main object and then assign a sub-object (defined as interface{}) to the response (which could be differernt type) as a reference which is not working for me.

Comment: Is your goal to set the type of field `b` before unmarshalling?  If so, see https://play.golang.org/p/mLznJZX7gB2.

Comment: @MuffinTop right this was what I wanted and it solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The goal is to set the type of field `b` before unmarshalling.  Use the following code:

```
func get(data []byte, r interface{}) error {
    res := struct {
        A string
        B interface{}
    }{
        B: r,
    }
    return json.Unmarshal(data, &res)
}
```

Call it like this:

```
func main() {
    var b string
    get([]byte(`{"a": "XYZ", "b": "Nobody"}`), &b)
    fmt.Println(b)

    var i int
    get([]byte(`{"a": "XYZ", "b": 10}`), &i)
    fmt.Println(i)
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/mLznJZX7gB2).

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an `interface{}` by value into your `get` function.  Since it's passed by value, your `r = &res.b` assignment is overwriting the value in your function, which has no effect on the value contained within the reference.

In other words:

- `r`  an `interface{}`
- that refers to a pointer
- that points to a `string` or an `int`.

Your code modifies the local value of `r` to reference a new pointer to a `string` or an `int`, ignoring and discarding the original pointer passed in.

If you want to modify the target of pointer, you need to access it. Use a type conversion (such as `if rstringptr, ok := r.(*string); ok { ... }` or a type switch) on your interface type to get to appropriately typed value referenced within it.  This may even let you simplify your API, since you don't need to supply the type in a separate argument.  For instance:

```golang
import "fmt"

func get(iface interface{}) {
  switch concrete := iface.(type) {
  case *string:
    *concrete = "Nobody"
  case *int:
    *concrete = 10
  }
}

func main() {
    var b string
    get(&b)
    fmt.Println(b)
    
    var i int
    get(&i)
    fmt.Println(i)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/JyYRjH9Dchj

```
Nobody
10
```

Comment: You didn't read my question correctly. tRes is dynamic and I get by calling an API which I do not have control on. I cannot add a switch case whereas comment in the question helped to solve the issue.